# Apache Poi and dependencies

Tags: android, excel, dependencies, apache-poi

Im using android studio and I try to make a simple example to read xls and xlsx. Instead of using HSSF and XSSF I used WorkBookFactory to read both files. 
Im successfuly read the XLS file but I have a lot of errors trying to read the XLSX file.
 I posted the code Im using and dependencies and errors I got in this link [Apache POI- 4.1.2 - java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61880098/apache-poi-4-1-2-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror/62012393#62012393)
I tried to add some dependencies like XmlBeans but Im still having the same errors. I read about the apache.poi.ss (read xls and xlsx) but cant find the dependencies to add to android.
Thanks
Gastón

Comment: Instead of posting a question as an answer and then linking that false answer here, you should provide the whole story here. But `Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamReader"` is pretty celar. `Apache POI` relies  on a default `java` class to read `XML`. The class `javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamReader` is part of default `Java Runtime Environment`s but seems not be part of `android`. As often it shows `android` != `java`.

Comment: Alex, thanks for your answer. Yes you're right, but instead to re-post the same issue I create this one to explain more What I want to do.

Comment: Apache POI is a Java library not an Android library. However, people to repackage it with the dependencies changed to work within the Android restrictions, why not use one of those, eg https://github.com/centic9/poi-on-android ?

Comment: thanks Gagravarr. I found it before posting. Thanks for your help.